# Javascript/React filtering array based on value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

```
{
  "team_list": ["Bob Hill", "Jack Duncan", "John List"],

  "team_data": {
    "Bob Hill": { "role": "member" },
    "Jack Duncan": { "role": "captain" },
    "John List": { "role": "member" }
  }
}
```

If I have an object as such, how can I use .filter() (or any other method) to filter  out the the people whose role isn't "member" in order to result:

```
{
  "team_list": ["Bob Hill", "John List"],

  "team_data": {
    "Bob Hill": { "role": "member" },
    "John List": { "role": "member" }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please paste all the code here instead of using screenshots.

Comment: Do you really need `team_list`?

Comment: I think this object is bad configured,you cant use filter on different names as keys,should think about new configuration for that object.

Comment: @Goran_Ilic_Ilke I agree that it would be better as an array, but you can filter an object, by filtering `Object.entries()`, for example, and reducing it to an object again.

Comment: @Goran_Ilic_Ilke It depends. Sometimes is makes sense, especially when the object is being indexed for performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the condition that every member of `team_list` also has an entry in `team_data`, you can do the following:

```
const memberEntries = Object.entries(obj.team_data).filter(
  ([name, attributes]) => attributes.role !== 'member',
);

const membersOnly = {
  team_list: memberEntries.map(([name]) => name),
  team_data: Object.fromEntries(memberEntries),
}
```

Comment: @Manish Bhandari Did this solve your problem?